# submitting a form through node as if connected to a site

Tags: node.js, authentication, https, request

I'm trying to create an automated tool that will submit a form so that it can detect changes in the response over time.
Normally, to submit this form I log in to a site and submit the form.
When trying to send the exact same request through Postman or a small node app I made, I get status 302 (while resending the request through firefox debugger works fine).
I even tried to use the HAR exported from the browser.
this is the code I use:

```
request({
har:{
    "bodySize": 320,
    "method": "POST",
    "url": "https://***.com/url-to-send-the-form",
    "httpVersion": "HTTP/2.0",
    "headers": [
        {
            "name": "Host",
            "value": "www.***.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "User-Agent",
            "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0"
        },
        {
            "name": "Accept",
            "value": "*/*"
        },
        {
            "name": "Accept-Language",
            "value": "en-US,en;q=0.5"
        },
        {
            "name": "Accept-Encoding",
            "value": "gzip, deflate, br"
        },
        {
            "name": "Referer",
            "value": "https://***.com/page-where-the-form-is/"
        },
        {
            "name": "Content-Type",
            "value": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
        },
        {
            "name": "X-Requested-With",
            "value": "XMLHttpRequest"
        },
        {
            "name": "Content-Length",
            "value": "320"
        },
        {
            "name": "Cookie",
            "value": "visid_incap_1156372=***; _pk_id.7.32fa=***; _pk_ref.7.32fa=***; ASP.NET_SessionId=***; __RequestVerificationToken=***; BIGipServerMFT-Frontends=***; incap_ses_1051_1156372=***; _pk_ses.7.32fa=***; windID_1b5aa482-1126-4c17-a65f-dbac1e05cfb9=***; .AspNet.ApplicationCookie=***; family_Composition=***"
        },
        {
            "name": "Connection",
            "value": "keep-alive"
        }
    ],
    "cookies": [
        {
            "name": "visid_incap_1156372",
            "value": "***"
        },
        {
            "name": "_pk_id.7.32fa",
            "value": "***"
        },
        {
            "name": "_pk_ref.7.32fa",
            "value": "***"
        },
        {
            "name": "ASP.NET_SessionId",
            "value": "***"
        },
        {
            "name": "__RequestVerificationToken",
            "value": "***"
        },
        {
            "name": "BIGipServerMFT-Frontends",
            "value": "***"
        },
        {
            "name": "incap_ses_1051_1156372",
            "value": "***"
        },
        {
            "name": "_pk_ses.7.32fa",
            "value": "***"
        },
        {
            "name": "windID_1b5aa482-1126-4c17-a65f-dbac1e05cfb9",
            "value": "***"
        },
        {
            "name": ".AspNet.ApplicationCookie",
            "value": "***"
        },
        {
            "name": "family_Composition",
            "value": "***"
        }
    ],
    "queryString": [],
    "headersSize": 1717,
    "postData": {
        "mimeType": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "params": [
            {
                "name": "key",
                "value": "{val}"
            }
        ],
        "text": "key=val-url-encoded"
    }
}
}, function (error, response, body) {
console.log(response.statusCode);//returns 302
});
```

Help will be very much appreciated

Comment: Use the network tab in the browser debugger to see EXACTLY what is being sent to the server (cookies, headers, URL, request data) when the POST happens from a web page.  Then, duplicate that exactly in postman.

Comment: Postman won't let me send the referer and Cookie headers without postman interceptor. My goal is to use node for sending the request

Comment: So, my comment stands.  Use the network tab in the browser to see EXACTLY what the browser is sending and send that in node.js.  Not sure what you expect us to be able to help with beyond that.